# CN name for 2 Way SSL Certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a question on CN mane for my CA certified certificate. My application is running on Azure cloud. The certificate I received from CA (Venafi) has a CN name set to appname_mycompayname.com (appname.clm.com). My question  is do I need a CN name of domain where my application is running (azure.com) or my company domain (clm.com) will work too.

Thanks,

Comment: If it's a server cert, you need a Subject Alternative Name entry for whatever DNS name someone will use to talk to you, and the CN is irrelevant.  If it's a client auth cert, you need to match whatever the rules are for the entity you're presenting it to.  If it's used as both, don't do that... get a second cert and follow the rules individually.

Comment: Thanks, I have 2 different certificates. Certificates generated through openssl there is no Subject Alternative Name, while as the certificate generated by Venafi Alternative Name (DNS) has name as appname.clm.com.